# Hashtag inside \begin{Arabic} \end{Arabic}

Tags: xetex, arabic

When I do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[]{Geeza Pro Regular}
\csname @Latintrue\endcsname

\begin{document}
\begin{Arabic}#بالحزن\end{Arabic}
\end{document}
```

why does the hashtag come out as a square?

Comment: Would you complete the example so that it can be compiled and we can see which font you’re trying to use?

Comment: \usepackage{fontspec}   
    \usepackage{polyglossia}  
    \setmainlanguage{english}  
    \setotherlanguage{arabic}  
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[]{Geeza Pro Regular}  
    \csname @Latintrue\endcsname

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a freely available font? Not many of us will have Geeza Pro to play with.

Comment: please give me an idea of such a font?

Comment: Amiri? It’s in TeX Live.  I just found a copy of Geeza Pro, and it has no open type features and no scripts defined, so you’ll have trouble getting a decent output with it.

Comment: ah, OK. So I should use a font other than Geeza Pro to do the Arabic I guess? (a Latex newbie, in case you hadnt guessed)

Comment: @BenderRodriguez You can use a font that is not freely available like Geeza Pro, but most of us do not have such fonts to play with. Therefore, when you are asking questions, please use a freely available font. Of course, you can choose whatever font that suits your needs when you are applying the answers to your own document.

Comment: Two things: 1. Remember to load your font with `[Script=Arabic]` 2. Regarding the hashtag, type `\#` instead of just `#`.