# Underscore in Arabic

Tags: xetex, arabic

The following:

```
\begin{Arabic}بالدم_فريق_السحمان_مايروح\end{Arabic}
```

does not print the whole sentence,

```
\begin{Arabic}بالدم_فريق_السحمان\textunderscore مايروح\end{Arabic}
```

also doesnt work,

```
\begin{Arabic}السحمان_مايروح\end{Arabic}\textunderscore\begin{Arabic}بالدم_فريق\end{Arabic}
```

does work, but adds an extra space after the underscore.

is there a better/proper way to do this, or remove the space?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a minimal and complete example of your code and a sample output image. It will make it a lot more easier for us to help!

Comment: Welcome back! As in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481448/hashtag-inside-beginarabic-endarabic, could you provide a complete example to test things out? Preferably with a freely available font like Amiri.

Comment: \documentclass[]  
%for arabic - start  
\usepackage{fontspec}  
\usepackage{polyglossia}  
\setmainlanguage{english}  
\setotherlanguage{arabic}  
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Geeza Pro Regular}  
\csname @Latintrue\endcsname  
%for arabic - end  

\begin{document}  
  \#\begin{Arabic}بالدم_فريق_السحمان_مايروح\end{Arabic}  
\end{document}

Comment: cant get the linebreaks to appear...supposed be 2 spaces at the end of the line, but not working.

Comment: do not add code to comments (as you see, it doesn't work) add the test document to your question then use the `{}` button to mark it as a code block. Then all line endings are shown naturally and need no special markup

Comment: Very similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489525/a-problem-with-hebrew-and-english-underlined-text

Comment: Shouldn’t there be braces around the text to be underscored?

Comment: No, because I just want the underscore character on its own, e.g. this_is_it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\_` to include a literal underscore in Arabic just like for other text. For RTL text, this *looks* like `_\`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\begin{document}
this\_is\_it
\begin{Arabic}بالدم\_فريق\_السحمان\_مايروح\end{Arabic}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]